# Docker-compose: Container is not running

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I created the following Dockerfile:

```
 FROM postgres
 COPY short_codes.csv /var/lib/postgresql/data/short_codes.txt
 ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And docker-compose:

```
 version: '3'
services:
    codes:
      container_name: short_codes
      build:
        context: codes_store
      image: andrey1981spb/short_codes

      ports:
         - 5432:5432
```

I up docker-compose successfully. But when I try to enter in container, I receive:

"Container ... is not running"

I suppose, I have to prescribe some run-command in Dockerfile. But what is this command?

Comment: add in your compose file restart:always

Comment: restarting a failed container is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your container is probably not running because you haven't copied your docker-entrypoint.sh script anywhere to your container.

You also don't need to supply a run command, since entrypoint is going to run a command on start up, and docker-compose up auto runs your container.

Comment: I add "entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh" in docker-compose.  But without result

Comment: Please read my answer. You need to COPY the entry script to the container.

Comment: I add "COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /var" in Dockerfile. But container still not runned. Or I have to change content of this script?